# CSS Style module for React App not picking up style after deploying it to Kubernetes

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I have a react app and I am using some node modules that have Navtabs

```
import { Nav, NavItem} from '@{some-module-example}/components';
```

Now these Nav components require

```
import '@{some-module-example}/components/styles'
```

These styles are applied on their own in local.
Now the issue is when I run the app in my localhost the CSS styles are being applied, but when I deploy it to K8 using github actions, the styles are not picking up. The styles that are being picked up are the ones in index.html (After using the inspect tool).

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://{xyz-example.com}/style.css">
```

Any idea how can I achieve these styles only for those specific components from

```
import '@{some-module-example}/components/styles'
```

Answer (score 0):

This was resolved by adding - `import '@{some-module-example}/components/styles/styles.css'` so that it overrides.